# How to determine which device & os version of simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, finder

I get bunch of serial numbers when I explorer following.

```
 cd ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
```

[image]

I exactly know which simulator (for example iPhone 5 with iOS8.1) I've used to run my application. But sometimes, I find it difficult to explore simulators to check documents directory & other stuff. Everything is with serial number.

Is there a trick to explore simulators with ease like follows?

- iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1
- iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 8.1 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the shell script for above request.

```
cd ~/Desktop
mkdir Simulators_Shortcuts
destination="`pwd`/Simulators_Shortcuts"
cd $destination
cd ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
for d in *; do
    if [ -d $d ] ; then
        cd $d;
        deviceName=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :deviceType" device.plist | sed -e 's/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.//g'`
        osName=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :runtime" device.plist | sed -e 's/com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.//g'`
        linkName="$deviceName-$osName"
        currentPath=`pwd`
        ln -s $currentPath "$destination/$linkName"
        cd ..
    fi
done

cd $destination
```

Here is the snap-shot of what is the output as folders.

[image]

Comment: You should probably use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` to read those values from a `.plist` file.  Will be alot cleaner and more reliable.

Comment: Assume, I'm using PlistBuddy, even after having exact link file, I am not able to move link to specific folder. I get errors like this - `mv: rename source/iPad-2-iOS-8-1 to ~/Desktop/Simulators_Shortcuts: No such file or directory`

Comment: You should post a question about it, if you need help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just run `xcrun simctl list` to see what each simulator device's UDID is or you can just pull it out of device.plist directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to get to the simulator's tmp, documents or other folders of the app running in Simulator using Swift. Put this in the AppDelegate.swift didFinishLaunchWithOptions, and it will provide an output of the file path in the console window. Then you can copy that and paste into the Finder > Go > Go To Folder...

```
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().model == "iPhone Simulator" || UIDevice.currentDevice().model == "iPad Simulator" {
        var locale:String = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).description
        locale = (locale as NSString).substringFromIndex(8)
        locale = (locale as NSString).substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length:(locale as NSString).length - 1))
        println("\n\n\(locale)\n\n")
    }
```

Here's a sample output from the console window of Xcode:

```
/Users/brope001/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/59E93965-6DEA-4A06-95EC-01FA155226D7/data/Containers/Data/Application/59115DEA-25C7-4400-8548-8A6ADD02E339/Documents/
```